# Why does not Files.newByteChannel return FileChannel?

Tags: java, nio

`java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel` returns `SeekableByteChannel`. But actual class of the object returned is `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl` (in my Java) so I can cast it to `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` and use it as a FileChannel. Does anybody know the reason why `Files.newByteChannel` cannot return `FileChannel`?

Comment: You ask for a ByteChannel, it gives you a ByteChannel, looks fine to me. sun.* is not part of the API and making explicit use of it will tie your application to a specific VM (and a specific set of versions of that VM).

Comment: @ignis I'm not sure if this is where the question was coming from, but since the method is implemented in `Files` it would kind of make sense for a `FileChannel` to be returned.  I might think differently if `Files` extended some class where `newByteChannel` was originally defined, but that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know the reason why Files.newByteChannel cannot return FileChannel?

[`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)(abstract class) implements [`SeekableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) interface.

Generally it is always good practice to use `object reference of interface` instead of class because if we change the implementation then we do not need to change the code everywhere.